# FlutterPlugin vs FlutterActivity

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

for my Flutter App I want to write myself a small plugin which is using the camera natively in Android.

I was going through the documentation, and I got a basic understanding of the "glue" between Flutter and Native with MethodChannels. There is one thing I don't understand though:

What exactly is the difference, if my native class of the plugin is implementing a FlutterPlugin and ActivityAware, or if I use An Activity directly which is extending FlutterActivity and also connecting to the Flutter engine?